# what is Matching Funding in grant application?

Tags: funding

I am filling my project Grant Application

There is one section in that application that i do not know what is it and what to write there.

**14. Matching Funding**

What is it? and what to write there?

[image]

Comment: The concept is very googleable. If you want an answer better than that, you should provide more details, such as the grant scheme name. https://www.dummies.com/business/nonprofits/grants/how-to-uncover-matching-funds-for-your-grant-application/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matching funds (money) are

- Funds not provided by the funding agency and
- Funds that will will be provided to the project if the grant is awarded by the funding agency

Usually they come from your university's research office, but they might come from any other unit of your organization or any third party.

Read your funding agency's rules about matching funds and ask the program officer if you are not sure.  Rules vary widely, even within an agency.